# RxJava - Wait for all Services' Observable<Boolean> in Observable<List<Service>>

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I'm trying to make a manager that monitors whether all services in an `Obsevable<List>` are ready.

The general concept of the code looks similar to this:

```
public class ServiceStuff {

    public interface Service {
        String getName();

        Observable<Boolean> monitorReady();
    }

    private BehaviorSubject<List<Service>> services = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(Collections.emptyList());

    ServiceStuff(List<Service> list) {
        services.onNext(list);
    }

    public void addService(Service service) {
        List<Service> newList = services.getValue();
        newList.add(service);
        services.onNext(newList);
    }

    public void removeService(Service service) {
        List<Service> newList = services.getValue();
        newList.remove(service);
        if (newList.remove(service)) {
            services.onNext(newList);
        }
    }

    public Observable<List<Service>> monitorServices() {
        return services.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }

    public Observable<Boolean> monitorServicesReady() {
        return [If monitorReady() for all services return true, emit true, else false]
    }

}
```

How can I implement the `monitorServicesReady()` method without blocking the UI thread? It should be possible to start monitoring before any services are added to the list.

---

Update:

I have now tried to implement the the solution cyroxis suggested with some modifications. `blockingIterable()` is however ANRing the app since it never knows when the `monitorServices()` stream ends.

```
public Observable<Boolean> monitorServicesReady() {
    Iterable<Observable<Boolean>> sources = monitorServices().flatMapIterable(x -> x).map(Service::monitorReady).blockingIterable();
    return Observable.combineLatest(sources, this::all);
}

private boolean all(Object[] values) {
    boolean result = true;
    for (boolean val : (Boolean[]) values) {
        result &= val;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean  `monitorServicesReady()` should not block UI thread?

Comment: @SaeedMasoumi Yes, I've updated the question. I'd preferably like to solve this without any `blockingGet()` :)

Comment: `Services` list might change over time, am I right? Is it a reason why it's in subject?

Comment: @skywall That's correct, I've updated my question.

Comment: So it turns out that combineLatest needs `List<Observable<Boolean>>` and your combiner (e.g. `all`) takes an Object[] type can't use Boolean[] so you will have to cast inside the method.

Comment: @cyroxis The thing is that the first parameter in `combineLatest(sources, this::all)` has to be `Iterable<Observable<Boolean>>`. But I don't want to do a `blockingIterable()`, because that blocks the UI thread, right? Or will that be noticeable for the one calling `monitorServicesReady()`?

Comment: @MisseMask First will be no blocking of the UI thread in this case because there are no thread changes (`observeOn` or `subscribeOn`) so everything happens on the same thread. Secondly you could solve the problem by getting rid of the `Subject` from what I can tell it is just adding complication and is not needed.

Comment: @cyroxis Okay, so I've changed the `Subject` to a `BehaviorSubject` that can use `.getValue()` to get the current `List<Service>` (-> like "removing" the Subject as requested). I've also added Add/Remove `Service` functions. The `blockingIterable()` is however ANRing the app as now described above.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your services also implement `Observable`.
Then you can use `Merge` operator which is also an `Observable` triggered when all the services are ready.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two steps.

1. Get a list (or observable) of all the `Observable<Boolean>`'s from your 'Service` objects
2. Do a combine latest the collection you got in step 1

It could looks something like this.

```
private boolean all(Boolean[] values) {
  boolean result = true;
  for(boolean val : values) {
    result &= val;
  }
  return result;
}


public Observable<Boolean> monitorServicesReady() {
  Observable<Observable<Boolean>> sources = monitorServices.flatMapIterable(x -> x)
   .map(servie -> servies.monitorReady());

  return Observable.combineLatest(sources, this::all); 
}
```

**Note:** from what I can tell you should get rid of the `BehaviorSubject`, you have a fixed list of Services provided by the constructor just save that in your class as a `List`. `BehaviorSubject`'s should be avoided unless they are really needed.

Comment: I understand how you think! I just can't seem to get the syntax for the `combineLatest` right...

Comment: @Misklahr Can you post an update with where you are stuck?